# Can you create a new project through Quire API?

Tags: quire-api

How to create a new project through Quire API? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of now this function is not implemented (and not included in the [api-documentation](https://quire.io/dev/api/#tag-project) accordingly).

If this is an important feature for you, you can propose a feature [on github](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues) so others can vote for it as well. (Please only post specific bugs or feature requests there, for usage questions stackoverflow is the preferred forum)